# jQuery CSS Selector to Filter keyboard ENTER key

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a webpage that I am attempting to suppress the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key within a section of the page by using a jQuery trick I have seen on here to catch the `10` and `13` key codes.

```
<head>
  <title>Test Script</title>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('container content input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
      alert('Form Submission needs to occur using the Submit button.');
      e.preventDefault(); // should I call preventDefault() or return false?
      //return false;
    }
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

I do not know what this jQuery trick is called, so I do not know how to look it up to make sure I am doing it right.

I do not want to suppress **ALL** <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key presses, because these are used to trigger our *File Search* and *Employee Search* features:

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="FileSearch">
          <!-- Other HTML here -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <form id="testInput" action="HTMLTestPage1.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text1" />
        <input type="text" name="text2" />
        <input type="text" name="text3" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="EmployeeSearch">
          <!-- Other HTML here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

As you can see from my jQuery statement, I am trying to drill down into form using the `"container content input"` values.

It does not seem to be working well, though. Every time I press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key when the focus is on one of the  controls, the form is submitted.

I would like to see my **alert** dialog box pop up instead!

Is there any way to enable breakpoints for jQuery so a person can step into what is going on?

Comment: `should I call preventDefault() or return false?`  *preventDefault()* will prevent default action.  If you instead use *return false;* , it is equivalent to `e.preventdefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: So they produce the same results? Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/W2xFX/40/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code look's perfectly fine.

The missing part is the right selector

```
$('container content input')
```

supposed to be

```
$('.container .content input')
```

You are accessing the input based on the class attribute for the element.

And a class selector has to be prefixed with a `.` .

**If not it perceives it as a tag.**

> should I call preventDefault() or return false?

**preventDefault()** will prevent default action.

**return false** - equivalent to **e.preventdefault()** and **e.stopPropagation()**

To prevent the submit behavior of the form, remove the type="submit" for the button and submit the form on the click of the button.

```
$('.container .content input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
        alert('Form Submission needs to occur using the Submit button.');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('input[name="Submit"]').click(function (e) {
    $('#testInput').submit();
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTYpB/)**