# How Do I Trigger My jQuery Event?

Tags: jquery, css

I got my <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key issue resolved for my **INPUT** forms, and a JavaScript **alert()** box is displayed:

[jQuery CSS Selector to Filter keyboard ENTER key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20339415/153923)

The **alert()** box is not pretty, and I have been integrating something called [Cool notification messages with CSS3 and jQuery](http://dhirajkumarsingh.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/cool-notification-messages-with-css3-jquery).

In [Dhiraj's Demo](http://demo.web3designs.com/cool-notification-message-with-css3-and-jquery.htm), these notification messages fire when a hyperlink is clicked, but I don't see how he is wiring up his `click` event or what calls his `showMessage` function.

Could it be this snippet of his doc load method?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // ...  
  $('.message').click(function() {  
    $(this).animate({top: -$(this).outerHeight()}, 500);  
  });         
});
```

Since I am not getting the piece above, I don't know how to modify my piece of jQuery below to replace the **alert()** box with what he is using:

```
$('container content input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
    alert('Form Submission needs to occur using the Submit button.');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Instead of **alert()**, I want to see how to modify this so that I can say:

```
$('.container .content .row input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
    //alert('Form Submission needs to occur using the Submit button.');
    $(this).animate({top: -$(this).outerHeight() }, 500);
    return false;
  }
});
```

How do I pass a value indicating what style of box I would like to use?

How would I pass my text ("Form Submission needs to occur using the Submit button.") to a  tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the snippet of his code that is binding to the `click`:

```
$('.'+ type +'-trigger').click(function(){
    hideAllMessages();                
    $('.'+type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
});
```

You could simply change that event handler to your enter key:

```
$('container content input').keypress(function (e) {
    var type = 'error'; // use error message by default
    if (e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
        hideAllMessages();                
        $('.' + type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Then you'll need to put your error message into the error div:

```
<div class="error message">
    <h3>Ups, an error ocurred</h3>
<p>This is just an error notification message.</p>
```

... or you could pass the message in from Javascript as well:

```
hideAllMessages();
$('.' + type).find('h3').html('Your error title');
$('.' + type).find('p').html('Your error message');   
$('.' + type).animate({top:"0"}, 500);
```

**P.S.** - this code here is bound to when you click the **message** (to close it), not the button to create it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // ...  
  $('.message').click(function() {  
    $(this).animate({top: -$(this).outerHeight()}, 500);  
  });         
});
```